# How to pass variables from extensions options page to external .js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, parameter-passing

I am making a autofill extension for chrome. I would like to make it so when you type your name in a text box on the options page, then click a button, the value of the textbox (the persons name) is set as a variable in a .js file that is injected via content scripts.

Is this possible? Is there a better way of going about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not the way to do it.
In your options page you need to save the autofill data (probably in indexDb but for something trivial save to chrome storage.
Have the content script read data from there.